# Bitcoin private key and address generator in golang

Tags: private-key, address-generation, btcd, go-lang

I am looking for a golang alternative to https://github.com/richardkiss/pycoin . So far I have found https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd but have not figured out how to generate private keys and addresses using btcd. The Python pycoin has a very handy `ku` utility to generate private keys and addresses from integers.

Is it possible to generate private keys and addresses from integers using https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd ?

TIA.

Answer (score 2):

btcd does no support this functionality by design, however you can use btcwallet which is written in golang and support what you want

https://github.com/btcsuite/btcwallet

here is a similar question https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd/issues/1308